# Redirect undesirable domain

Tags: php, redirect

I have a wordpress site that i want to run 2 hosts with 2 different domains.

Site in the first host with the domain example1.com works correctly but in the second host domain example2.com redirect to example1.com domain.

There is no set redirect in the .htaccess file.

DNS of each of the 2 domains are set up correctly.

My question is how should I get it which part of the program code is this redirects ?

Comment: Options `home` and `site_url` are correct? Try adding to the `wp-config.php` file of **example2.com** wordpress:  `define('WP_HOME','http://example2.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example2.com');`

Answer (score 0):

### [Edit](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) functions.php

To be certain your WordPress site is pointing to the correct URL do this.

1. Got to your themes functions.php file found at [/wp-content/themes/](http://#) `theme-name`
2. Add these two lines to the file, immediately after the initial `<?php` line.

> update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
>
> update_option( 'home', 'http://example.com' );

3. Make sure you clear all cache and if using CloudFlare, put it into development mode.
4. Check you have no redirects in your `.htaccess` files
5. Now check to see if your site points to the correct URL.

If it doesn't it's likely you have a DNS setting that needs changing. Check your parked domains to make sure one isn't set as a redirect there as seen in the WHM setting I have on my server in the below image.

[image]

*Once you have solved the issue, it's a good idea to remove your added code from `functions.php`. If you don't you won't be able to change these settings in the WordPress setting until you do so.